# Set button's background to image, scaling as needed

Tags: java, android, button, scale

I have a simple layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="Button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is the output:

But I want the button with the background to stay the same size as it would without an image as a background (the right one). Basically, I want to "place" the button over the image so that the center of the image is on the button background, but the button doesn't resize to fit the whole background.

I have tried android:scaleType="centerCrop" on the Button but it didn't change anything. Any help is appreciated, thanks

[image]

**Edit** The size of the button needs to wrap_content because the text is dynamic

Comment: You should create 9patch for the image if you don't know the size of the button (wrap_parent). If you know the size of the button just set the size in layout_height / width and the image should scale correctly.

Comment: How does a 9patch resize? does it stretch/shrink to fit? I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: @user1282637 9patch is a PNG with metadata. It resizes based on how you create it. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button width and height are set to *wrap_content*. In this case, the background Image is a content, too.
Simply change width and height to the value you want:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="Button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

If you want all buttons to have the same size, consider creating a *dimen* value:

**Dimen**

```
    <resources>
        <dimen name="button_width">100dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="button_height">50dp</dimen>
    </resources>
```

**Layout**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_with"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="Button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_with"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Also, consider using a *ImageButton* for your purpose.

[ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

**EDIT**

Try this out:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/your_background"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonId"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonId"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonId"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonId"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonId"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Additionally, add a *scaleType* to the ImageView to make it centered, streched, whatever...

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

**EDIT 2**

adding padding to the button works for me:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_settings"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonId"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonId"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonId"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonId"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="This is a button with a very long text that may take up multiple lines and stuff"
        android:id="@+id/buttonId"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_settings"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonId2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonId2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonId2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonId2"
            android:scaleType="center"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a button with a very long text that may take up multiple lines and stuff"
            android:id="@+id/buttonId2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot two buttons]

*Note: You can't really see the paddingStart and paddingEnd in the screenshot, but it works just fine.*

Comment: Unfortunately the text in the button is dynamic and it might be multiple lines, so I can't set a height/width. I will check ou ImageButton though

Comment: And ImageButton's don't allow text :(

Comment: Yes that's what I just thought.  You should update your question, adding the info that the button size should vary with it's content.. I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: @user1282637 I added an edit that should answer your question.

Comment: This is working...however, I'm having trouble adding padding around the text to make the background bigger...no matter where I add it (imageview, button, layout) it pushing the background to be smaller. Also, I'm not sure how I would handle a ListSelector for this...I'll keep trying. thanks for the help

Comment: @user1282637 I adde a second edit, adding padding to the button works for me. I don't really know what you mean with ListSelector, but you can apply the same method of "alignStart" etc. to other views, all you need it an id.

Comment: Yeah after adding scaleType="centerCrop" the padding works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the nine-patch suggestion, Android supports the ability to use a nine-patch image to scale an image for a button/view group to any size.  One caveat is that the image has to be one that fits the nine-patch requirement -- generally speaking, image where the corners are constant, and the middle/edges must be able to scale to any dimension.  If your image is a photo for instance, it won't work.  Most nine-patch images have a solid color center and 'simple' edges.

The first step is to create a nine-patch drawable in your `drawable` folder that references your nine-patch image.  The nine-patch image should have a filename similar to *.9.png.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nine-patch
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/button_image" />
```

Once this is done, you can add the `background` property to the `Button` and it should scale seamlessly with the content (the `background` property below should refer to the `<nine-patch>` XML resource you created above.

```
<Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" 
        android:text="My button"/>
```

I will note that your image in particular, with the horizontal lines, looks like a bad candidate for the nine-patch solution, but it might be worth a look if you're flexible on the image used.